# Is there a way to display info messages for any Dr. Racket Exception?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, racket, interpreter

I currently have the following lines to try and test parts of code.

```
   (with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn) 'Error)]) (car 17))
```

I was wondering it there was any way to change 'Error to a function of the caught exception in order to help print out the reason why it failed?

I've also been using check-not-exn, but that function writes too much information to the console.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just print the exception to the console?

```
(with-handlers ([exn:fail? displayln]) (car 17))
=> #(struct:exn:fail:contract car: contract violation
     expected: pair?
     given: 17 #<continuation-mark-set>)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know displayln also worked for error info

Comment: @AndrewSU No problem. A good way to thank me is to mark my answer as correct.